# Project euler #8, wrong answer

Tags: python-3.x

I'm stuck on [Problem 8 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8), I can't seem to figure out what mistake I am making.

My answer is coming out to be `70573265280`. I am fairly new to programming.

I copied the number twice to check for any copying error and still got the same wrong answer.

```py
def count_nums(y):
    largest_product = 0

    while len(y) >= 13:
        sub_list = y[:14]
        product = 1

        for x in sub_list:  
            product *= x

        if product > largest_product:
            largest_product = product
        else:
            largest_product

        y.pop(0)

    return largest_product

x = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

x = [int(y) for y in x]
print(count_nums(x))
```

Comment: You should add the Euler's problemn definition so that we can help you

Comment: @Adirio sure, but the question says 13 digits, not 5.

Comment: And doing that still doesn't give the right answer.

Comment: I found a page that defined it as the five continous digits, thats why I said you should provide the problem's definition.

Comment: I added a way to change the number of continous digits to consider in my answer

Comment: @SarhaanGulati simply call @Adirio 's function as `count_nums(x, 13)`

Comment: `count_nums(x, 13)` returns `23514624000`, is that the expected solution?

Comment: [yes](https://blog.dreamshire.com/project-euler-8-solution/). Also in that link, a nice one liner solution

Answer (score 0):

### Euler's problem #8:

> Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit
>   number.
>
> ```
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
> 96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
> 85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
> 12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
> 66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
> 62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
> 30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
> 70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
> 65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
> 52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
> 53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
> 83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
> 82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
> 16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
> 17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
> 24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
> 07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
> 84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
> 05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
> 71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
> ```

---

### Fixes to your solution

First of all, give variables actual names, `y` is not a good parameter name and reusing `x` inside the function neither. The digit length should be 5 not 13 as you had. I also removed the `sub_list` variable as you were only using it once so no need to use a variable for it, and removed a no-op `else`.

```
def count_nums(items, n=5):
    largest_product = 0

    while len(items) >= n:
        product = 1
        for item in items[:n+1]:  
            product *= item
        if product > largest_product:
            largest_product = product
        items.pop(0)

    return largest_product


x = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

x = [int(y) for y in x]
print(count_nums(x))
```

---

### My solution

I would propose one additional improvement: using a range to iterate instead of popping items.

```
def count_nums(items, n=5):
    largest_product = 0

    for i in range(len(items)-n):
        product = 1
        for x in items[i:i+n]:
            product *= x
        if product > largest_product:
            largest_product = product

    return largest_product


x = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

x = [int(y) for y in x]
print(count_nums(x))
```